# Can't have tsconfig.json in Cypress-cucumber-typescript for React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cucumber, cypress

I have a project with React, [Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor), Typescript(output in es5).
When I run the cypress with [official example](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-typescript-example) or [another example](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-typescript-example/tree/master/cypress), it has those problems:

```
TypeScript error: cypress/integration/Google/google.ts(5,3): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cy'.

SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

If I delete `tsconfig.json` in React parent folder, it fixed the `Syntax Error` but it still has `TypeScript error`.
So it seems like `tsconfig.json` make this problem, but the project should not without `tsconfig.json`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig`?

Comment: @Brendan Yes, I posted it.

Comment: I suspect this is because you are only including `src` in your `tsconfig` so your tests aren't included.  try changing to this:  `"include": [ "src", "cypress" ]`

Comment: @Brendan It still has the same problems which Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cy'.

Answer (score 11):

for Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cy'.

you should add on top of your file:

`/// <reference types="cypress" />`

Answer (score 2):

I modified the **tsconfig.json** file from my project's root folder to ignore the **cypress** folder. Try this too to test, here it worked.

```
{
  //... tsconfig.json file
  "exclude": ["src/main/test/cypress"]
}
```

note: If you are using **eslint**, you will have to do one more configuration. Because eslint doesn't let us have a TypScrip file inside the project without being treated.

First: Create a file in the project root called tsconfig-eslint.json. It will extend the other tsconfig but ignore the deletion. Put the following content in it:

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
 "exclude": []
}
```

Second: modify the parseOptions of the **.eslint.json** file to point to the newly created file:

```
{
 //... rest of the settings
 "parserOptions": {
   "project": "./tsconfig-eslint.json"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the solution in this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4239#issuecomment-743722397)

> If you are using Cypress 3, the permanent link for the example is here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example/tree/cdc24ff6595190790b6bc2c973a084efe1c11de7/cypress/plugins

> If you are using Cypress 4.4+, TypeScript test files are supported without using special preprocessors plugins, so just ignore the linked example and read Cypress's official documentation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html